# I want to create chatbox kind of component in react which can be opened on bottom right and can be minimized

Tags: reactjs, react-native, popup

How can I create component like chatbox in react, my requirement is I have to place other controls in this box, actually this is not exactly chat kind of requirement but I want this to be opened on right bottom same like chatbox and user can minimize it?

Comment: Is this the sort behaviour you're looking for? https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel

Answer (score 1):

Make some kind of footer component that is always on the bottom of the page. At the right of the component you will then put another component with a click listener. When you click on that it will toggle this component and display it on the page. Inside this component you can put whatever controls you want.

Comment: Actually I have to open this component on one icon button which is present in Nav Menu Bar and also how can we achieve minimize functionality?

Comment: On this icon button you will write a `onClick` that will update the state of the chat window. When the state is getting updated you will then render the chat window in its open state (the maximized one) when you click the icon again, the open state will be set to false and it will trigger a rerender of the chat window and it will close, to minimize it you could for example use `display: none` for the chat window. To sum it up the click listener should update the state and based on that state different styles have to be applied to the chat window.

Comment: I got the concept but what about this component to be placed on bottom right?